# adb - How to remove the invisible new line character from a Python variable?

Tags: android, python, shell, monkeyrunner, monkey

I use the `MonkeyRunner` tool which provides an API in order to manage an Android emulator or device through a script written in `Python`. I have assigned a `process_id` of an application using `pid = device.shell('pidof [s] PACKAGE_NAME')` command. When I concatenate the `pid` with another string and print the result, I get a string which has 2 lines. I need to remove the reason for breaking new line from the variable `pid`. How can I trim the result in order to get the raw data of `pid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the string method `strip()`. It will remove whitespace characters from either end of the string.

```
pid = device.shell('pidof [s] PACKAGE_NAME').strip()
```